# Showing Image to all view controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ads

I'm quite new to iOS. I'm trying to show advertisements in every view controller's bottom side. But i don't want to load advertisements for each and every view controllers. Is there any other way to show the ImageView of that advertisement throughout all view Controller without loading the ads again and again?

Also those advertisement images should be changing regardless of the view controllers.i.e., whenever the user navigates to next page, the Next page's advertisement should continue from last page's advertisement. It shouldn't be load from the initial image.

For that, Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you use uitabbarcontroller or uinavigationcontroller for basic navigation of your app you could add the images to the uitabar or uinavigation bar. They wont relosd for switching tab or pushing new viewcontroller on your navigationcontroller.

Comment: Yeah. I'm using UINavigationController as Initial view controller.. How can i do that?

Comment: When you initialize the navigationController you have to add an Uiimageview to the navcontroller.navbar, you must set the frames of your imageview so that it showing as you desire. Following rect object may help you.[UiScreen mainScreen].bound